# Alternate iSCSI clients for OSX

Tags: macos, iscsi

I am looking for a iSCSI initiator that is not ATTO or GlobalSAN.

Comment: Just to add to Daniel's question, is NFS not an option as an alternative to iSCSi? What iSCSI device are you connecting to?

Comment: @Daniel Beck if you'd tried that Googling before posting the snarky comment, you'd see that it's not easy to find any other iSCSI initiators for Mac OS X, so it makes sense that someone would come here asking for tips in case there's a low-profile alternative out there.

Comment: @Spiff: watch your language!  We respect other users here, regardless of their knowledge level, we all started somewhere.

Comment: @studiohack I don't recall putting any bad language into my comment, and I don't see any there now. Did you edit it? "Snarky" is not a bad word. Mr. Beck deserved the admonition for hypocritically suggesting someone else Google something when it was *he* who had failed to Google.

Comment: I have spent tens of hours looking through Google, Bing and Yahoo for someone's pet project in the hopes that something had been ported from Linux or BSD with no luck.  I am interested to see if someone comes up with something because GlobalSAN isn't stable enough for me and ATTO gets great reviews and looks well implemented but as a student I can't afford it.  I would also be interested to know if anyone knows of any libraries for Python, C++, Java, etc...  For dealing with iscsi.